# How to disable Firefox add-ons update check on start

Tags: firefox, automation, firefox-addon, cron

I start Firefox (Linux) via command line using a cron-job. When there is no update for the add-ons, it starts up normally, then I can tell it what to do. However if there is an update for an add-on, then it ask whether to take that update or not. I don't have the ability to detect the pop up window and choose no.

**So, how can I disable all questions upon startup of Firefox?**

Questions like:

- Do you want to update add-ons?
- Do you want to upgrade Firefox?
- Do you want to open previous tabs or new session?

I pretty much would like to keep my version of Firefox the way it is and not have any questions asked.

When I start Firefox, I would like to have it start nice and clean without any questions.

Comment: I agree in general. When I open Firefox it's because I want to visit a webpage (immediately), not because I want to sit and wait for updates to be installed. This was a ludicrous design decision and I can't fathom how it's stuck for all these years.

Comment: This is a question for Superuser.

Comment: Most definitely a question for SuperUser.  We should migrate it rather than close it.

Comment: Id vote this up * 100 if I could. The answer is currently: You cant, you can only disable update checks completely. If anyone in FF reads this, how about:  1 let me start my freaking browser without annoying me Im in a hurry. 2: check for updates in BG and show a notification somewhere other than in my face.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the linux version is very different, under settings > advanced > updates, there are settings you can disable, that are concerned with the automatic searching for updates for firefoxx and its add ons.

In "about:config" you can set "Browser.sessionstore.enabled" to false, in which case firefox will not restore your tab state after a crashed browsing session.

Comment: Where is "about:config"?

Comment: in the address field, type about:config and hit enter; it'll take you to the editor of all of firefox's internal settings

Comment: this option is no longer in Firefox.  Would be nice to update with the current equivalent setting.  Looks like the relevant setting is `restore_from_crash`

Answer (score 2):

I went to [about:config](http://about:config) to search and disable all *.update.enabled

```
user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);,
user_pref("browser.search.update", false);
user_pref("extensions.update.enabled", false);
```

Otherwise it derails my Watir tests.

Comment: Works like a charm unless you have user.js overriding everything.  Grr... Copy that into user.js, or in my opinion, copy everything over to prefs.js and edit properties there.  User.js automatically overrides prefs.js, so I just deleted (backup first) user.js.  Those files are in C:/Users/youruser/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/yourprofile.default/prefs.js

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what functionality you need while FF runs, you may want to look into the safe-mode switch when starting Firefox:

```
/path/to/firefox -safe-mode
```

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_mode

Answer (score 0):

All those options should be in the standard settings of the application. From the command line, safe mode is what you want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset Firefox to default settings** from Help -> Troubleshooting information, it will keep your passwords cookies etc and you get clean start, I just did it few minutes ago, and it does work. No more addon check update every time( by the way I got that annoying thing when turned  on automatic update for the firefox)