# getting an unwanted messages from selenium-webdriver, how to hide that?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, ruby-1.9.3

I am using `selenium-webdriver` to automate web browser related tasks.But when i did the following getting a chunk of `messgaes` as below. Why so,can you tell me? and how to suppress it any idea?

```
irb(main):001:0> require "selenium-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\Program Files\SearchPredict\P
RFireFox
*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\Program Files\SpeedBit Video
Downloader\SPFireFox
*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\Program Files\Web Assistant\F
irefox
*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\Program Files\Iminent\webboos
ter@iminent.com
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {F17C1572-C9EC-4e5c-A542-D05CBB5C5A08} installed
in winreg-app-user
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on ffxtlbr@babylon.com installed in app-global
*** WARN addons.xpi: Add-on is invalid: Error: Directory C:\Program Files\Mozill
a Firefox\extensions\ffxtlbr@babylon.com does not contain a valid install manife
st
*** WARN addons.xpi: Could not uninstall invalid item from locked install locati
on
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {1FD91A9C-410C-4090-BBCC-55D3450EF433} installed
in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed
in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on m3ffxtbr@mywebsearch.com installed in winreg-app-
global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on avg@toolbar installed in winreg-app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on daplinkchecker@speedbit.com installed in winreg-a
pp-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on wrc@avast.com installed in winreg-app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG addons.manager: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\Program Files\SearchPredict\P
RFireFox
*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\Program Files\SpeedBit Video
Downloader\SPFireFox
*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\Program Files\Web Assistant\F
irefox
*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\Program Files\Iminent\webboos
ter@iminent.com
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..fbe37f7d8 browser=:firefox>
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Jaepetto i didn't still. Can you reopen the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321645/how-the-description-mentioned-hashmethods-work-in-ruby#comment19905772_14321645) or vote up!

Answer (score 2):

Your Firefox profile is checking for add-ons at startup.  I used to get this message a lot when I was developing a Ruby-based Selenium test in Windows.  Switching to Mac OS X and then later to Ubuntu actually seemed to take care of the problem for me, but since that's a bit extreme, there is a workaround you can do.

First, you'll need to set up a new profile in Firefox that doesn't check for add-ons at startup.  Here's a thread on the options you'll need to set on that profile: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105766/how-to-disable-firefox-add-ons-update-check-on-start).  Here's Mozilla's reference on how to use the Firefox Profile Manager, in case you need it:  [link](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)

Then in your Ruby code, where you have something like this:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

You need to add an option to tell Webdriver which profile to use.  It will end up looking like this, instead:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => "selenium_testing"
```

(Just replace "selenium_testing" with whatever you've named your new profile.)

You should then be able to start up Firefox without all those irritating warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by upgrading Firefox to an older version (worked well with Selenium-WebDriver). In my case, I had to downgrade back to `Firefox 18` and this version worked with `Selenium 2.27`

Check out [older versions of Firefox](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/)